# Create Custom MutableState<T> Holders

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Compose allows only a limited number of state-holders, including all the primitive data types, and a few extra add-ons, but does not support custom objects, or anything more complex like a `Path`. I wish to make sure that changes to these types are also observed well, and so I want to implement a custom extension for these, just like they have added the `mutableStateListOf()` for our convenience now. How can I go about doing this?

I have already dug deep through the source, and it ends in internal java classes so that's not very useful.

EDITH: As suggested by Commonwares, the idea is to somehow allow Compose to observe Mutable types as well as it observes the Immutable ones. Things like the immutable listOf() works fine, and I assume all the other immutable types do so as well, so how can I achieve the same behaviour for mutable types like Path, or as a matter of that fact, even a `MutableList`?

Thanks

Comment: "but does not support custom objects" -- [`mutableStateOf()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#mutableStateOf(kotlin.Any,androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotMutationPolicy)) seems to work for arbitrary types. What specifically are you looking for that is not offered by `mutableStateOf()`?

Comment: Try using `mutableStateOf(Path())` to trigger a recomposition upon modification (or even re-initialisation)

Comment: That is not a matter of "complexity". It is a matter of *mutability*. `Path` is mutable (or, more accurately, the `Path` interface exposes an API designed for mutability, and implementations of `Path` are mutable). You get the same problem with using `mutableStateOf()` a `MutableList` or `MutableMap` -- changing the contents of the list or map does not trigger recomposition. The `State` system strongly prefers immutable types.

Comment: Yes that's true. This is why the immutable `listOf()` works, but what I want to ask is whether there is something that can be done to make it observable like the others.

Comment: Your question, though, does not discuss mutability of the objects. That is why I asked the question in my original comment. You might want to rewrite your question to focus on whether there is a way to help the `State` system work with mutable types like `Path` and its implementations. My guess is that the answer is "no" (as otherwise we probably would have heard about it on Kotlinlang Slack), but that is just a guess.

Comment: I have tried to implement a class to implement MutableState<String> interface, It can compile, but it do not work.
MutableState<String> is just looks like a pointer(from golang or c) to a real type.It works to write a wrap MutableState<String> management class like MyMutableStringHashTable, get the MutableState<String> by key if needed.