# Jetpack Compose Checkbox Not Showing Changed State

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-checkbox

I have a list of specialties from which the user will check. After the user is happy with their selection, I will gather the information for selected checkboxes and save those specialties in the user's profile.

However, when I tap any of the checkboxes, the state in the view model changes but checkbox is still unchecked.

**Specialty List**

```
@Composable
fun SpecialtyList(
    viewModel: SpecialtyListViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navController: NavController
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        item {
            viewModel.specialtyList.value.forEach { specialty ->
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(10.dp),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Checkbox(
                        checked = specialty.isSelected,
                        onCheckedChange = {
                            specialty.isSelected = it
                        },
                        colors = CheckboxDefaults.colors(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                )
                    Text(
                        text = specialty.name,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Specialty View Model**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SpecialtyListViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    // HARD-CODED PROPERTIES
    val specialtyList = mutableStateOf(
        mutableListOf(
            Specialty(name = "Emergency Medicine", isSelected = false),
            Specialty(name = "Forensic Medicine", isSelected = false),
            Specialty(name = "General Practitioner", isSelected = false)
    )
}
```

**Specialty Model**

```
data class Specialty(
    val name: String,
    var isSelected: Boolean
)
```

Comment: right now your `LazyColumn` is not really lazy, because you're displaying all the rows inside one `item`. Instead you can use `items(viewModel.specialtyList.value)` or `itemsIndexed(viewModel.specialtyList.value)` (as you need the index according to my answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for `mutableStateOf` to trigger recomposition, the container value should be updated, e.g. `specialtyList = newValue`.

There's no way how it can know you've changed one of inner objects.

Generally speaking, `data class` is a great tool to be used immutable in functional programming. If you won't use `var` inside them, you'll exclude many mistakes.

Using `mutableStateListOf` if your case seems much cleaner. In your view model:

```
private val _specialtyList = mutableStateListOf(
    Specialty(name = "Emergency Medicine", isSelected = false),
    Specialty(name = "Forensic Medicine", isSelected = false),
    Specialty(name = "General Practitioner", isSelected = false)
)
val specialtyList: List<Specialty> = _specialtyList

fun setSpecialtySelectedAtIndex(index: Int, isSelected: Boolean) {
    _specialtyList[index] = _specialtyList[index].copy(isSelected = isSelected)
}
```

Use it from your composable like this:

```
viewModel.specialtyList.value.forEachIndexed { i, specialty ->
    // ...
    onCheckedChange = {
        viewModel.setSpecialtySelectedAtIndex(i, it)
    },
}
```

You can find more info about state in Compose in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly not how Compose would work. Read more in the documentation, but for now, the fix would be to replace your existing VM implementation with this

```
@HiltViewModel
class SpecialtyListViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    // HARD-CODED PROPERTIES
    val specialtyList = mutableStateListOf(
            Specialty(name = "Emergency Medicine", isSelected = false),
            Specialty(name = "Forensic Medicine", isSelected = false),
            Specialty(name = "General Practitioner", isSelected = false)
    )
}
```

You cannot wrap anything inside a call to `mutableStateOf` and expect it to trigger recompositions. See this question: [Create Custom MutableState<T> Holders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977622/create-custom-mutablestatet-holders)

EDIT: Based on the comment by @Philip below to your post, it came to my attention that you are also wrongly implementing the `LazyColumn`. You must place every element in a separate `item` for the column to effectively cache and discard elements per need.

```
@Composable
fun SpecialtyList(
    viewModel: SpecialtyListViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navController: NavController
) {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {    
         viewModel.specialtyList.value.forEach { specialty ->
             item{
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(10.dp),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Checkbox(
                        checked = specialty.isSelected,
                        onCheckedChange = {
                            specialty.isSelected = it
                        },
                        colors = CheckboxDefaults.colors(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                )
                    Text(
                        text = specialty.name,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a minor swap. You can also leverage other ways of implementing this, for example, using the `items` block.