# Mutable State Checkbox Not Changing Appearance After Selection - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mutable, lazycolumn

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70040541/jetpack-compose-checkbox-not-showing-changed-state).  I tried these solutions along with some others and still not having any success.

I have a checklist for different options in a dialog in Jetpack Compose.  When an optionItem is selected I can see that the state has changed, but the checkbox icon won't update.

```
val _optionItems by remember {
    mutableStateOf(
        optionItemArray!!.map {
            OptionItem(
                label = it.label,
                value = it.value,
                number = it.number,
                type = it.type,
                subtitle = it.subtitle,
                group = it.group,
                matchType = it.matchType,
                isSelected = it.isSelected,
                isHidden = it.isHidden,
            )
        }
    )
}

val optionItems: MutableList<OptionItem> = _optionItems as MutableList<OptionItem>

fun setOptionSelectedAtIndex(index: Int, isSelected: Boolean){
    (_optionItems as MutableList<OptionItem>)[index] = _optionItems[index].copy(isSelected = !isSelected)
}


LazyColumn {
        items(optionItems.size) { i ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable
                    {
                        optionItems.mapIndexed { j, item ->
                            if(i == j){
                                setOptionSelectedAtIndex(i, item.isSelected)
                            } else item

                        }
                    }
                    .padding(16.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
            ) {
                optionItems[i].label?.let { Text(text = it) }
                if (optionItems[i].isSelected) {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Filled.CheckBox,
                        contentDescription = "Selected"
                    )

                } else {
                    Icon(
                        Icons.Filled.CheckBoxOutlineBlank,
                        contentDescription = "Not Selected"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the list is supposed to be called again, which is what I was assuming the `setOptionSelectedAtIndex` function was supposed to do, but I'm having quite a lot of trouble figuring this out.

Comment: I think the issue is here `(_optionItems as MutableList<OptionItem>)[index] = _optionItems[index].copy(isSelected = !isSelected)` because you are not updating the value of `mutableState`which is `MutableList<OptionItem>` you are just changing item of that list. You need either clone that list after changing the property and set value or use `mutableStateListOf<OptionItem>`

Comment: but again mutableStateListOf doesn't check for updates you will need to remove and add for it to be updated.

Comment: I ended up toggling the state of the checkbox at the same time that I toggle the state of the data.

`.clickable
                    {
                        optionItems.mapIndexed { j, item ->
                            if(i == j){
                                setOptionSelectedAtIndex(i, item.isSelected)
                            } else item
checkedState.value = !checkedState.value
                        }
                    }`

This does work, but it may not be the best solution.