# How to implement the MutableState interface in a custom class / make object observable for Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, observable, android-jetpack-compose

I have a more complex object that I want to be observable for Jetpack Compose. However I can't use

```
// in my view model
var observableProperty by mutableStateOf(myObject)
```

because I need `myObject` to keep it's reference. So my plan is to use

```
// in my view model
var observableProperty = myObject
```

and make `myObject` itself implement the [MutableState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/MutableState) interface. However I don't understand how one can implement this in a custom class, especially how to raise a change notification to the observer (Jetpack Compose)?

Reduced example of what I currently have:

```
class MyComplexObject(){
    private val map = mutableMapOf<String,Any>()

    fun setValue(key: String, value: Any) {
        map[key] = value
        
        // how to notify about a change? <================
    }

    fun getValue(key: String) : Any? {
        return map[key]
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is already present at : https://stackoverflow.com/q/68977622/15880865

Comment: hmm, the linked question doesn't have an answer and it's also not that much focused as mine I think, where I have included a code example to make the issue more clear. So I hope that's a good reason for my own question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to make your complex object implement MutableState. You can create a complex object that contains `mutableState`s and other objects that doesn't need to trigger recomposition on change. It's a common pattern as in [JetSnack app.](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/home/search/Search.kt)

```
@Stable
class SearchState(
    query: TextFieldValue,
    focused: Boolean,
    searching: Boolean,
    categories: List<SearchCategoryCollection>,
    suggestions: List<SearchSuggestionGroup>,
    filters: List<Filter>,
    searchResults: List<Snack>
) {
    var query by mutableStateOf(query)
    var focused by mutableStateOf(focused)
    var searching by mutableStateOf(searching)
    var categories by mutableStateOf(categories)
    var suggestions by mutableStateOf(suggestions)
    var filters by mutableStateOf(filters)
    var searchResults by mutableStateOf(searchResults)
    val searchDisplay: SearchDisplay
        get() = when {
            !focused && query.text.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.Categories
            focused && query.text.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.Suggestions
            searchResults.isEmpty() -> SearchDisplay.NoResults
            else -> SearchDisplay.Results
        }
}
```

And you wrap this object with remember to prevent to not instantiate on each recomposition

```
@Composable
private fun rememberSearchState(
    query: TextFieldValue = TextFieldValue(""),
    focused: Boolean = false,
    searching: Boolean = false,
    categories: List<SearchCategoryCollection> = SearchRepo.getCategories(),
    suggestions: List<SearchSuggestionGroup> = SearchRepo.getSuggestions(),
    filters: List<Filter> = SnackRepo.getFilters(),
    searchResults: List<Snack> = emptyList()
): SearchState {
    return remember {
        SearchState(
            query = query,
            focused = focused,
            searching = searching,
            categories = categories,
            suggestions = suggestions,
            filters = filters,
            searchResults = searchResults
        )
    }
}
```

Any changes in any of the `MutableState`s will trigger recomposition in Composable scopes these values are read.

remember functions that are commonly used such as rememberScrollState  and some others also use this approach either.

```
@Stable
class ScrollState(initial: Int) : ScrollableState {

    /**
     * current scroll position value in pixels
     */
    var value: Int by mutableStateOf(initial, structuralEqualityPolicy())
        private set

    /**
     * maximum bound for [value], or [Int.MAX_VALUE] if still unknown
     */
    var maxValue: Int
        get() = _maxValueState.value
        internal set(newMax) {
            _maxValueState.value = newMax
            if (value > newMax) {
                value = newMax
            }
        }

    /**
     * [InteractionSource] that will be used to dispatch drag events when this
     * list is being dragged. If you want to know whether the fling (or smooth scroll) is in
     * progress, use [isScrollInProgress].
     */
    val interactionSource: InteractionSource get() = internalInteractionSource

    internal val internalInteractionSource: MutableInteractionSource = MutableInteractionSource()

    private var _maxValueState = mutableStateOf(Int.MAX_VALUE, structuralEqualityPolicy())
 // Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for that reply and pattern idea. Yet I would prefer to directly implement the interface (for syntactic sugar reasons an ducriousity how it can be done)

Comment: I posted this as an alternative. Another alternative would be overriding `structuralEqualityPolicy ` to determine how recomposition should be triggered instead of using default one which triggers recomposition when new instance is set as `value` of `MutableState`. For an example how to implement `MutableState` you can check out `SnapshotMutableStateImpl` in source code.

Comment: Unfortunately, trying to put MutableStates to my class properties, I get "Type 'MutableState<TypeVariable(T)>' has no method 'getValue(RowsOfWords, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate"